# What is the name of this colorscheme

Tags: vim

Can anyone tell me whats the name of this colorscheme?[its from vim's wiki page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LrYz.png)

Comment: It's Wikipedia, you can find [who uploaded the image and contact him directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:AzaToth).

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of similar schemes.  Looks similar to http://vimcolors.com/432/aquamarine/dark[aquamarine](http://vimcolors.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&bg=dark&order=newest&page=1)

You can browse full color schemes [here](http://vimcolors.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&bg=dark&order=newest&page=1)

Comment: Thanks but i want the exact one. Btw does vimcolors.com contain all of the popular ones?